# Error 1215: cannot add foreign key constraint in my SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, workbench

I have the parent table which is gym_member, and I have the child which is medical_history.

In gym_member table there are two primary key which are gm_id and student_id.

In medical history table there are one primary which is mh_id, and I want to add a foreign key which is student_id but it show me this error.

```
ALTER TABLE `hct_gym`.`medical_history` 

ADD CONSTRAINT `student_id`

  FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`)

  REFERENCES `hct_gym`.`gym_member` (`student_id`)

  ON DELETE NO ACTION

  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `hct_gym`.`medical_history` 

ADD CONSTRAINT `student_id`

  FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`)

  REFERENCES `hct_gym`.`gym_member` (`student_id`)

  ON DELETE NO ACTION

  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

I want to know where is the problem?

Comment: Is the column hct_gym.gym_member.student_id a primary key or other key?

Comment: jarlh - yes this column is primary key

Answer (score 2):

Check if column `medical_history`.student_id contains values
which are not contained in `gym_member`.student_id

That would contradict the constraint before /while it is being created.